# Yii2 basic framework message language

Tags: php, yii2, frameworks, multilingual

I have created 4 columns in database which are title_en, title_ru, content_en, content_ru. however, I dont know what to do next, The datas are going to database successfully but I dont know how to switch the language and what to write in controller and models and views, please can you help to manage it

Comment: Hi man, just read the official documentation: this is common guide http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-i18n.html, and this is database message source http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-i18n-dbmessagesource.html

Comment: bro,, i could not understand the official documentation, but if you know how to do it, please help me, I need to find how to make multilingual in database very soon

Answer (score -1):

You can learn from this tutorial.

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-program-with-yii2-localization-with-i18n--cms-23140

You may swtich language with jquery ajax request.

```
public function actionChangelang(){
        $language = $_GET['lang'];
        if($language =='en' || $language == 'uz' || $language == 'ru'){
            Yii::$app->language = $language ;
            Yii::$app->session->set('lang', $language); //or $_GET['lang']
        }

        $this->redirect('/'); // redirecting user to somewhere
    }
```

After that, you may write query in controller like this:

```
...
$model = Yourmodel::find()->all();
...
//TODO
```

In view :

```
$lang = 'ru';
if (Yii::$app->language == 'uz')
    $lang = 'uz';
if($lang=='uz'){
    $title = $model->title_uz ;
    $content = $model->content_uz ;
}else{
    $title = $model->title_ru;
    $content = $model->content_ru;
    }

...
//TODO

echo $title;
echo $content;
```

Comment: Dear Sardor aka, bu yolini yordam.uz da menga o'rgattiz :-), endi databaza yoli bilan qilishni bilmayapmanda, masalan databazada table_uz, kegin table_ru degan column ochib, kegin sayt rus tilida bo'lsa, ruscha chiqadigon qilishni bimayapman :-)

Comment: mana tepada shu bo'yicha savol beribsizku! sizda qanday kiritiladigan datalar bo'lsa hammasi uchun 2 ta column qilishiz mumkin bu bitta usul. 2- usul: misol uchun post degan table bor, `title`, `content`, `language`, `slug` degan ustunlariz bo'ladi, `slug` - ikkita tilda ham bir xil qiymat berasiz va shu orqali postni `language` ustuni bo'yicha zapros berib olaverasiz